# Let X be uniform [-2,4] find the CDF and PDF of $Y=X^2$

Tags: probability

Let X be uniform [-2,4] find the CDF and PDF of $Y=X^2$

PDF for X is 1/6 for [-2,4]

$$P(Y\le y)=P(X^2\le y)=P(-\sqrt y \le X\le \sqrt y) = \int_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y}1/6dt=\frac{\sqrt y}6+\frac{\sqrt y}6=\frac{2\sqrt y}6$$
I'm kind of switching between the lowerbound being -2 and $-\sqrt y$ to get the CDF then get the derivative

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is OK for $0<y<4$. for $4 <y <16$ the integral is from $-2$ to $\sqrt y$ and for $y >16$ we get $P(Y\leq y)=1$.

Comment: can you explain why it should be -2? I'm used to seeing $X^2$ the derived distribtution being from $-\sqrt y \le X \le \sqrt y$

Comment: @user8714896 The density of $X$, $f_X(x)$, is $0$  when $x <-2$. So the integral to the left of $-2$ vanishes. You are taking the density as $\frac  1 6$ even when $x <-2$ and that is a mistake.

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused can you write out the solution with an explanation? I don't get how $-\sqrt y$ to $\sqrt y$ gets 0 to 4 and how -2 to $\sqrt y$ gets 4 to 16